# Dynamically deleting QLineEdit in PyQT4

Tags: python, pyqt

So I am dynamically creating QLineEdit's from a range:

```
        for w in range(x):
            s = "s"+str(w)
            self.s = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            self.s.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, y, 20, 40))
            self.s.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(s))   
            self.s.show()
            y += 40
```

I am looking to delete those later. I have tried a bunch of things, but it only deletes the last one I add. I can't find anything explaining why:

```
for w in range(x):
    s="s"+str(w)
    self.s.deleteLater()
```

It works for the last one, but none before that. So it will delete the bottom one of the lists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for w in range(x):
    s="s"+str(w)
    self.s.deleteLater()
```

You are setting `s` to the name of the QLineEdit, but then you're deleting `self.s`, a different variable altogether, which is set in the first loop to the last created QLineEdit.  I think you want something like this:

**Creating**

```
self.edits = []
for w in range(x):
    s = "s"+str(w)
    s = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
    s.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, y, 20, 40))
    s.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(s))   
    s_name.show()
    self.edits.append(s)
    y += 40
```

**Deleting**

```
for s in self.edits:
    s.deleteLater()
```